# What are the infrastructure design parameters for Hashgraph based Marketplace App

Tags: blockchain, infrastructure

We are designing a Hashgraph based Supply Chain Ledger with provisions for micro payments. What are the environmental parameters of Hashgraph DLT Architecture that we need to consider while we apply for an enterprise deployment license.

Answer (score 1):

Hashgraph platform has internet layer and consensus layer. Following articles and videos helped me to identify the Hashgraph DLT Environment design parameters.

https://cryptoticker.io/hedera-hashgraph-architecture/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6tQySZjXKc

While we design Hashgraph based DLT platform, we should factor the following design parameters as per the platform architecture mentioned below :

1. Event Types Requirements
2. Consensus  Requirements
3. Transaction Ordering Requirement
4. Transaction Voting Requirement
5. File Storage Requirements
6. Stakeholder Fairness Requirement
7. Data Replication Requirements
8. State Replication Requirements
9. Data Synchronization Requirements

[image]